# Block multiple nested frame-src via CSP

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

If the parent page wants to block certain nested frame sources, you can use the Content Security Police `frame-src`. But I want to block certain nested frame sources if the frame itself contains other frames. Can this be one via CSP?

For example:

- `parent.com` `<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src child.com"></head><iframe src="child.com"></iframe></html>`
- `child.com` `<html><iframe src="grandchild.com"></iframe></html>`
- `grandchild.com` `<html><script>alert('xss');</script></html>`

In the above case, I want to be able to load `child.com` but then block any frames on `child.com` that do not match my CSP.